# slapd.conf is missing on debian 9

Tags: ldap, debian, openldap

### Install openLDAP command on debian 9

sudo apt install slapd ldap-utils ldapscripts

### Question

I can only find the ldap.conf on /etc/ldap directory, but not find slapd.conf. Now I want to define my objectclass , anybody can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, and here is the hint.
https://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/OpenLDAPSetup#Missing_slapd.conf.3F

Answer (score 0):

The Debian wiki linked by @winwin has had the relevant information removed, however it is still available in a historical version of page: https://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/OpenLDAPSetup?action=recall&rev=122#Missing_slapd.conf.3F

For posterity the relevant information is as follows:

---

Since version 2.4.23-3 the configuration of OpenLDAP has been changed to /etc/ldap/slapd.d by default. The OpenLDAP packages in Debian provide an automatic migration to the new configuration style. With the new configuration style it is possible to change values on the fly without restarting slapd. Changes are made through the use of ldif files and ldap{add,modify}. In Debian you can use the following command to search the configuration:

```
ldapsearch -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b "cn=config"
```

To modify configuration use the command:

```
ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f <file.ldif>
```

For configuration options see the several manpages that exist or the documentation provided upstream.

The use of slapd.conf remains possible (optional).